# Как парсить авторизованно на сайте на языке Python?

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Не получается авторизоваться в парсере, вроде все параметры передала, а возвращает неавторизованную страничку... =(

Вот сам сайт https://www.mir-priaji.ru

Вот что получаем вводя левые данные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что получаем, зайдя в аккаунт:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import urllib
import fake_useragent

session = requests.Session()

link = 'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/auth/?login=yes'
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random

header = {
    'user-agent': user
}

data = {
    'backurl': '/auth/',
    'AUTH_FORM': 'Y',
    'TYPE': 'AUTH',
    'POPUP_AUTH': 'N',
    'username': 'почта по которой захожу',
    'password': 'действующий пароль',
    'Login': 'Войти',
    'Login': 'Войти',
}

responce = session.post(link, data=data, headers=header).text

href = 'https://www.mir-priaji.ru/personal/'
progile_responce = session.get(href, headers=header).text

print(progile_responce)
with open("hh_success.html","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(progile_responce)
```

Comment: У вас вот здесь: `Не получается авторизоваться в парсере` неточность. Парсером фактически является модуль `bs4`, который не создает запросов к удаленному серверу. Собственно в самом коде явно видно, что запрос отправляется через `requests.Session`. Вот в нем вы и авторизовываетесь.

Comment: Возможно, формулировка вопроса не совсем верна, простите...

Comment: да суть не в извинениях. Важно уточнить этот момент, что бы исключить непонимание корня проблемы с вашей стороны.

Answer (score 0):

В браузере Firefox раздел formdata отображается иначе.
То есть так:
"Login": [
"Войти",
"Войти"
]
Таким образом всё работает.